# I'm trying to open 2 video lightboxes separately. But, both anchors open the same video. Assistance greatly appreciated

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the HTML. It is a bit extensive, but the main priorities are the anchor onclick and the video element:

```
  <div class="video-content">
    <div class="video">
      <h2>Intro <span>Video</span></h2>
      <a href="#" class="openLightbox" onclick="lightbox_open('.introVideo');">
        <figure class="videoWrap">
          <img src="./images/pictures/video-temp.jpg" />
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <div class="episode">
            Episode 0<br>
            Introductions<br>
            9/9/23<br>
            8m 32s
          </div>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
 
    <div class="light">
      <a href="#" onclick="lightbox_close();"></a>
      <video class="introVideo" controls width="600" autoplay preload="auto">
        <source src="./video/preview1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src="./video/preview1.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <p>
          Your browser doesn't support this video. Here is a
          <a href="./video/preview1.mp4">link to the video</a> instead.
        </p>
      </video>
    </div>
 
    <div class="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
 
    <div class="video">
      <h2>Latest <span>Video</span></h2>
      <a href="#" class="openLightbox" onclick="lightbox_open('.latestVideo');">
        <figure class="videoWrap">
          <img src="./images/pictures/video-temp.jpg" />
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <div class="episode">
            Episode 1<br>
            Saved From What?<br>
            9/9/23<br>
            8m 32s
          </div>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
 
    <div class="light">
      <a href="#" onclick="lightbox_close();"></a>
      <video class="latestVideo" controls width="600" autoplay preload="auto">
        <source src="./video/preview2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <source src=".video/preview2.webm" type="video/webm" />
        <p>
          Your browser doesn't support this video. Here is a
          <a href="./video/preview2.mp4">link to the video</a> instead.
        </p>
      </video>
    </div>
 
    <div class="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
 
  </div>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
window.document.onkeydown = function (e) {
if (!e) {
e = event;
}
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
lightbox_close();
}
};

let currentVideo = '';

function lightbox_open(className) {
  const lightBoxVideo = document.querySelector('.openLightbox');
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  document.querySelector('.light').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('.fade').style.display = 'block';
  currentVideo = className;
  const videoPlayer = document.querySelector(currentVideo);
  videoPlayer.play();
}

function lightbox_close() {
  const lightBoxVideo = document.querySelector('.openLightbox');
  document.querySelector('.light').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.fade').style.display = 'none';
  const videoPlayer = document.querySelector(currentVideo);
  videoPlayer.pause();
}
```

I tried using .closest, but that didn't work. Again, I'm trying to open each HTML5 video separately. What am I missing here? I'm not sure what more details I need to add here. If you need more details, please let me know.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is reproducible with just the code you have shown so far - https://jsfiddle.net/2jg50s7c/ I added a `console.log(videoPlayer)` at the end of your `lightbox_open` function - and that clearly shows the _correct_ video element, when each of these anchors gets clicked. But this doesn't look very "lightboxy" to begin with, presumably there's CSS missing, that would achieve any lightbox-like effect. I can only guess here, that due to the CSS you are probably not clicking the link you actually _think_ you are clicking.

Comment: If I add the css to your jsfiddle, will you be able to see it? I'm new to jsfiddle.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What more code do you need?

Comment: It would be much easier to use a feature-ready lightbox script like Fancybox.

Answer (score -1):

You have declared `currentVideo` has a global variable that gets updated when you open a lightbox but it cannot distinguish between videos, so you need to keep a record of video associated with each anchor. You can pass the classnames to store the record.

```js
window.document.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (!e) {
    e = event;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    lightbox_close();
  }
};

let currentVideoElement = null;

function lightbox_open(className) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  document.querySelector('.light').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('.fade').style.display = 'block';
  currentVideoElement = document.querySelector(className);
  currentVideoElement.play();
}

function lightbox_close() {
  if (currentVideoElement) {
    document.querySelector('.light').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('.fade').style.display = 'none';
    currentVideoElement.pause();
    currentVideoElement = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me how to do this? I'm still a JavaScript newbee. Thanks!

Comment: I have added the code in my answer by editing it

Comment: It doesn't work.